# How do I wait till table is loaded on the webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have to read data from [this](https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain) site.
The table loads few seconds later after we hit the page.

I am using PYTHON + SELENIUM code to read the data from table with some default seconds (20) of delay, but that is too bad as the data is dynamic and I want to optimize to the point that as soon as table is loaded I should be able to read and process it.

For this I tried waiting till the time element (id - equity_timeStamp) is loaded using following code :

```
myElem = WebDriverWait(webdriverFire, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'equity_timeStamp')))
```

But even the presence of this element also doesn't guarantee the presence of data (as above just checks for the element's presence but not the text inside it). I also thought of using `EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, 'equity_timeStamp'))` but the text is not a constant.

I know I should wait for something but everything that is useful has dynamic text.

Comment: Please try `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="equity_timeStamp" and text()!=""]'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try **`visibility_of_element_located`** because **`presence_of_element_located`** doesn't guarantee visibility of the element

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try to use the `implicit wait` method. This can be useful when certain elements on the webpage are not available immediately and need some time to load. You can see the selenium docs. about waits here https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the `equity table` use `visibility_of_element_located`() and following css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table#optionChainTable-indices")))
```